# How to check the number of updates in the Sales and Trends Module of iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have a question that is not exactly code-related. However, I thought that I would ask it here because many developers seem to have some experience with this issue.

Recently Apple updated its Sales and Trends module to a different interface. I used to be able to check to see how many updates I had for an app each day by clicking on an "updates" tab.

However, in this new module, I cannot seem to find this feature! I really need to have access to something like this and I was hoping to be able to continue to depend on Apple's website to find this information.

Comment: Perhaps they removed it due to iOS 7's new auto update feature.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Click Filters, click Transaction Type from the drop down, and click "Updates".

[image: iTC screenshot showing filter by updates]

**Update 07/06/15:**
It's still pretty similar: Click Add Filters->Transaction Type, then click Updates.

[image: Updated iTC screenshot 1]

[image: Updated iTC screenshot 2]

Comment: ...and how is it done now? This doesn't seem possible anymore.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: They changed the design again. Any help as of Oct 2015@?@?

Comment: @BeemerFan Nope, same as my 07/15 update: Click Add Filters->Transaction Type, then click Updates.

Answer (score 5):

Update Feb 2020: The filter doesn't offer the "Transaction type" option right off the bat. First click on "Units" on the left panel. Then you will have "Transaction type" as part of the filter.

Comment: @Denny are you sure? I just checked. Click on "Units " first on the left. Send a screenshot

Comment: I find if fine under Units, however it seems like it does not work as before, the numbers make no sense. E.g. for an app with 16k lifetime units sold, my last update (you can filter by version) shows 35k units! Like more than double my users upgraded???

Comment: @Ecuador do you have just one app? How many updates did you do? (one user can update to version 2.0, 3.0, ...) Are you sure about the total lifetime units sold? Or was it the number for the last 90 days?

Comment: I have several apps, it happens across all of them. Yes, I compare lifetime units vs lifetime updates per version. The aforementioned app that has sold 16k over 5 years if I break down lifetime upgrades per version, the numbers go like 10k, 11k, 13k for versions start of '18 to mid '19 then jump to 33k and 35k for my last to versions. They were always less than units sold before, now more than twice. I mailed Apple support as well...

Comment: curious to see what Apple says, I just checked and don't have this issue (on both a recent app and an old app)

Comment: OK, so Apple replied that downloads are unique per ID, while updates are per device. This seems like something that could explain it (assuming users average 2+ devices each - kind of a stretch), however it does not tell me how the same app that would get just under 100% update rate for the first dozen+ updates until 2019, suddenly got 200%+ update rate for just the last two updates (they were not more "important" in some way). I'll let it go at this point, but I am still puzzled... Unless updates WERE per ID before? They didn't say so though...

Comment: interesting... also users don't change phones the same day (except a bit more around the release of a new iphone). Thanks for following up on this